# What is the MLE of $~(x_1,\cdots,x_n)~$ realizations with pdf $~λ~x^{-2}~$?

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to find the maximum likelihood estimator for parameter $~λ~$ in the above, I am pretty sure differentiation will not work in this case, so there should be another way. Any ideas?

my pfd is $~λ~x^{-2}~$, so the joint pdf I found it to be: $~λ^n ~ Π(xi)^{-2}~$

Comment: There is no parameter to estimate.  For $\lambda x^{-2}$ to be a pdf (for a continuous distribution with $1\leq x < \infty$) then $\lambda$ must be 1.  If this is for a discrete distribution with integer values for $x$ being from 1 to $\infty$, then $\lambda=6/\pi^2$.

Comment: Pdf makes no sense without support of distribution. Here it must be $\{x: x>\lambda\}$.